# Python can't resolve modules import when running unittests

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have a project with the following structure:

- project/

  - source/

    - __init__.py
    - module1.py
    - module2.py
  - integration_tests/

    - __init__.py
    - test_module1.py
    - test_module2.py

In the file `integration_tests/__init__.py` I have some util functions to be used across all unit tests, and also the test class (e.g.: `test_module1.py`) import the corresponding module to be tested (e.g.: `module1.py`).

The following is an example of `test_module1.py`:

```py
import unittest
import module1 # target module to be tested
from . import util_method # import test util method

# My tests come here
```

I'm running my tests from the root directory `/project` with the following commands:

```bash
export PYTHONPATH="$(pwd)/source"
python -m unittest discover -s integration_tests
```

However, when I run these commands I get the following error:

```py
======================================================================
ERROR: test_method (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: test_method
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/unittest/loader.py", line 436, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/unittest/loader.py", line 377, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/project/integration_tests/test_module1.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import util_method
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 8 tests in 0.002s

FAILED (errors=8)
```

How can I fix the command lines or the program to run these tests from the parent directory?
Note I want to run only the tests inside `integration_tests`

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I think using `from integration_tests import util_method` should work.